# "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers, error how to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

So I was creating a card using redux toolkit and this is features/store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {cardReducer} from "./cardSlice";

const store = configureStore({
   reducer: cardReducer
});

export default store;
```

And exported to main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import  store  from './features/store.js';


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Also this is the cardSlice.js file

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cardSlice = {
    name: 'card',
    initialState: {
        cards: [],
    },
    reducers: {
        createCard: (state, action) => {
            cards: [
                ...state.cards,
                {
                    id: state.cards.length + 1,
                    name: action.payload.name,
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

export const cardReducer = cardSlice.reducer
export const createCard = cardSlice.actions
```

I have checked several times and checked answers on stack-overflow but not able to resolve this error.

Comment: In `cardSlice.js`, the `cardSlice` object has no `reducer` property, so `cardSlice.reducer` in `export const cardReducer = cardSlice.reducer` is exporting `undefined`. (The same problem exists for `cardSlice.actions`.)

Comment: should it be `export const { createCard  }= cardSlice.actions`

Comment: @AkhilAravind- There's no `cardSlice.actions` property either, as I pointed out above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as per the documentation, `cardSlice ` object should be wrapped inside `createSlice()`, which is missing here

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if we wrap the `cardSlice` object with `createSlice()`, it should work, https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice

Answer (score 1):

You imported `createSlice` without using it.

if you create a slice it **must** be inside the `createSlice` fn.

```html
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cardSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'card',
    initialState: {
        cards: [],
    },
    reducers: {
        createCard: (state, action) => {
            cards: [
                ...state.cards,
                {
                    id: state.cards.length + 1,
                    name: action.payload.name,
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});

export const cardReducer = cardSlice.reducer
export const createCard = cardSlice.actions
```

** For good practice you should export your createCard inside {} as you'll need to create more reducers as delete, edit etc...

```html
export const {createCard, futureReducers...} = cardSlice.actions
```